# Show hidden visibility text on key press with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

I have this javascript that is activated when the enter button is pressed. It does detect the keystroke, and even sets the background image. But the elements for secret and/or secrettext are not toggled to be seen. I would like for it to toggle the visibility.

JS

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) {
$("#backgroundjake").css('backgroundImage', 'url(' +'images/bw_c1.jpg'+ ')');
$("#secret").show();
$("#secrettext").show();
```

HTML

```
<div id="secrettext">
<textarea id="secret"  style="height:200px;width:400px;font- size:14pt;visibility:hidden;"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a nice clean way is to toggle a class with a visibility (or opacity if you wanted to fade in/out) CSS property.

E.g.

```
$("#secrettext").addClass("show");
```

with the CSS:

```
#secrettext.show{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7xhLa2uq/

Comment: This works great. Thanks for the fiddle, it works just how I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

just change `$("#backgroundjake").css('backgroundImage', 'url(' +'images/bw_c1.jpg'+ ')');`
 To

```
$("#backgroundjake").css('background-image', 'url(images/bw_c1.jpg)');
```

invalid syntaxe

```
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $("#backgroundjake").css('background-image', 'url(images/bw_c1.jpg)');
    $("#secret").show();
    $("#secrettext").show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like this:

```
 $("#secret").css({"visibility":"visible"});
```

Answer (score 1):

`secret` is nested inside `secrettext`, so you need not hide or show them both, just hide and show `secrettext` alone, its enough.

Then inside document ready function, use;

```
$("#secrettext").hide();
```

and remove the css `visibility:hidden` property.